# how to output double pointer function?

Tags: function, return, double-pointer

This is a function made to read 2d arrays

```
   int** readDurations(int rows, int cols)
{
int *reval[rows][cols];
int myArray[rows][cols];

ifstream inputFile;
int SizeRow;
int SizeCol;
inputFile.open("duration2.txt");
SizeRow=rows;
SizeCol=cols;

string *arr= new string[SizeRow*SizeCol];

for (int row = 0; row < SizeRow; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < SizeCol; col++)
    {
        inputFile>> *(arr + SizeCol * row + col);

    }
}

for (int row = 0; row < SizeRow; row++) //////////////TO TEST PRINT
{
    for (int col = 0; col < SizeCol; col++)
    {
        cout << *(arr + SizeCol * row + col) << " ";
        myArray[row][col]=stoi(*(arr + SizeCol * row + col));
    }
    cout << endl;
}

for (int row = 0; row < SizeRow; row++) //////////////TO TEST PRINT
{
    for (int col = 0; col < SizeCol; col++)
    {
        cout<<myArray[row][col]<<' ';
        reval[rows][cols] = &myArray[row][col];
    }
    cout<<endl;
    }

   return *reval;
}
```

just want to get the value that is read from the 2d array on file from the file and saved in to an array.
i am not sure what to return and how ho initialize in Main();
PS: file reading and out put is okay , just dont know how to implement the function on main to give the value that it took.
thank you , appreciate it.